# How to add new platform to libGDX project?

Tags: libgdx

I have a core and a desktop project, and I also need an android project. It would be great if Gradle did all things for me so I don't have to edit Gradle files manually.

Comment: Cleaned up the English and removed unnecessary commentary.

Comment: so you cleaned up [the English](http://img.memecdn.com/tell-me-more-about-it_o_3079121.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Follow the following Steps:

1. Go into you libgdx Set Up

[image: GDX setup]

2. Check Desktop, and Android and whatever you want to include
3. After you finished generating project, import it to whatever editor you use.
4. Copy your 'core' code into your new 'core' project
5. Cory your 'Desktop' code into you new 'Desktop' project
6. Enjoy yourself having a new Android Project :)

Comment: But my project is already in the middle stages and I want to add **gdx-tools** now. But in the documentation, it is mentioned that you should not add gdx-tools dependency in `core` in `gradle` file, but only on `Desktop`. Should I download `Desktop` subproject now to include gdx-tools? I now have `core` and `android`.

Comment: Can you please explain step 4?

Comment: @BlackPanda I suggest that you should start a new topic to ask your question specifically. I can't help you in the comments due to the lack of information you have provided.